# Apply schema on javascript object

Tags: javascript

I suppose this may be rather widespread situation that you have some incoming POST or GET parameters stored in json. However, these parameters come from some html-form and may be not in good shape - e.g. some numbers or dates may be sent as strings, some validation is needed, default values, etc.

Is there some way to define a kind of "schema" of a document I would expect, say

```
var sch = { "name": {"type": "string", "required": true},
            "birthday": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy-mm-dd"},
            "role": {"type": "string", "default": "user"}
          }
```

so that later I could apply it in some way to incoming document and it would convert all necessary types, formats, fill in default values or throw exception if validation failed

```
var verified = apply(get_params_json, sch);
```

Comment: Roll your own specific checks, or use http://json-schema.org/

Comment: There are a number of Javascript input validation plugins. See the `jquery-validate` and `jquery-validation-engine` tags if you use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

There are some project which can help you. For example: [schema.js](https://github.com/akidee/schema.js)